# Salesforce / Docusign intagration

Tags: apex, docusign

I am working on a setup of sending documents to be signed from Salesforce to Docusign, via their APEX toolkit.  At this time I am doing almost a straight copy of the example code they have at the following url:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/multi-send/

The code is failing in Section 2.  Here is my small rework of the code they have presented.  I have only changed how the document is added to the envelope, as it isn't stored linked to a contact, like their example.

```
public PageReference Send_Envelope(){
        //Step 2, Start of the document signing process now
        quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        // Getting contact and signer info
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id,Name,Phone,Email FROM Contact where Id IN (:quoteDetail[0].AccountContact__c,:quoteDetail[0].Co_Signer__c)];
        
        // Build a list of offer envelopes to send
        List<dfsle.Envelope> envelopes = new List<dfsle.Envelope>();
        for (Contact c : contacts) {
            system.debug('contacts Name = ' + c.Name);
            // Get an empty envelope with org defaults
            envelopes.add(dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope(new dfsle.Entity(c.Id))
                          // Customize the email subject and message
                          .withEmail('Quote for ' + c.Name, c.Name + ', please review and sign the enclosed Quote.')
                          // Add linked offer letter to envelope
                          .withDocuments(dfsle.DocumentService.getDocuments(Document.getSObjectType(), new Set<Id> { attachId }))
                          // Add the contact as a recipient
                          .withRecipients(dfsle.RecipientService.getRecipients(
                              //RoutingOrder(1),
                              Contact.getSObjectType(),
                              new Set<Id> { c.Id })));
        }
        
        // Send the envelopes and determine which envelopes were sent successfully
        // Filter out unsuccessfully sent envelopes
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        List<dfsle.Envelope> sentEnvelopes = new List<dfsle.Envelope>();
        for (dfsle.Envelope envelope : dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelopes(envelopes)) {
            if (envelope.error == null) {
                // Envelope sent successfully
                sentEnvelopes.add(envelope);
                contactsToUpdate.add(new Contact(
                    Id = envelope.source.id,
                    Department = 'Sent'));
            } else {
                // Handle send error
                System.debug('Envelope error: ' + envelope.error);
            } 
        }
        
        // TAKE USER TO PARENT RECORD
        return new PageReference('/'+quoteId);
        
    }
```

When this code runs I get the following error message

> Attempt to de-reference a null object
> Error is in expression '{!Send_Envelope}' in page docusignquote_202008_vp: >Class.Print_Docusign.Send_Envelope: line 82, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified..

Line 82 happens to be the following.

```
Contact.getSObjectType(),
```

I don't see why this might be happening.  While I believe this is a Docusign function, I assume there is something wrong with my code.  I don't see it so far.  I know that the 'contacts' array has entries in it.  The same function seems to be working fine for the document process.  Is there something I am missing in this?

Comment: Are you sure that the Docusign method accepts `Schema.SObjectType`?  You'll need to check with Docusign support resources.

Answer (score 1):

So I have finally figured this out. Ton of reading in the apex guide and a bit of insight based on that. I believe that there was an error in the code that was published by the Docusign website.  That line 82 was the following on the URL that I posted.

```
Contact.getSObjectType(),
```

I got it work with this line of code instead

```
C.Id.getSObjectType(),
```

It needed a field to check to get the Object type of, i.e., in this case the C.Id field is part of a SOBject type for a contact record. 'Contact' wasn't valid for that code, C.Id is a valid field for that code.  It both compiled clean and the code ran and did what was expected. woot woot